# Sorting linked list in C++ fails at runtime

Tags: c++, class, sorting, linked-list

```
    void head_insert(DomesticPtr& head, string firstNameD, string lastNameD, string province, float cgpaD, int researchScoreD, int idD)
{
  DomesticPtr temp_ptr;
  DomesticPtr temp2;
  temp_ptr= new DomesticStudent(head, firstNameD, lastNameD, province,cgpaD,researchScoreD,idD);
  temp2 = head->getLink();
      temp2==temp_ptr;
      head=temp_ptr;
      if (head->getLink() == NULL)
          return;
      else
      {
          bubblesort(head);
      }


}

void bubblesort(DomesticStudent* head)
{
 int  rsd;
 int cgpad;
 int p;
 DomesticPtr tempc, tempd, tempe;
 tempd=head;
 tempe= head->getLink();
    {
 while(tempd != NULL)
   {                                                   
      rsd=compareResearchScore(tempd, tempe);

                if (rsd==1)
                  {
                    tempc=head;
                    head->next=head;
                    head=tempc;
                  }// if
                else if (rsd==0)
                  {
                    cgpad= compareCGPA(tempe,tempd);
                    if (cgpad==1)
                      {
                    tempc=head;
                    head->next=head;
                    head=tempc;
                      }// if (cgpad[k]>cgpad[k+1])
                    else if(cgpad==0)
                      {

                        p=compareProvince(tempd,tempe);
                        if(p==1)
                          {
                        tempc=head;
                        head->next=head;
                        head=tempc;
                          }// if (p[k]>p[k+1])
                      }//
                      }// else if cgpad[k]
                      }// else if rsd[k]
                //  }
// }
                tempd = tempe;

}






  int compareResearchScore(DomesticPtr RSA, DomesticPtr RSB)
{
    if (RSB == NULL || RSA==NULL )
    {
        return 0;
    }
  if (RSA->researchScoreD==RSB->researchScoreD) //compares if is the same for domesetic students returns value for bubble sort
{
  return 0;
}
  if (RSA->researchScoreD > RSB->researchScoreD)
         {

           return 1;
}
  if (RSA->researchScoreD< RSB->researchScoreD)
         {
           return -1;
}
}
```

I'm trying to to have my linked list sorted every time a new node is inserted. It compiles but every time I try to run the program it is stuck on the point that I am trying to print my list. I have a destructor but no copy constructor or assignment operator. 
The head_insert calls the sort function and the sort function calls the compare function to receive an integer output so that it can make a swap. I want to compare research, the cgpa, and then province. Any input would be much appreciated, this is for a project so I wouldn't like any blocks of code but if you could point me in the right direction or multiple directions.

Comment: Did you debug it through line by line to determine what is happening and where exactly it fails and how?

Comment: The "right direction" you need to be pointed to is your debugger, which lets you run your program one line at a time, while showing you the values of all variables, as they change, and observe your program's logical execution. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer. No exceptions.